# yii2 Date validation is not working

Tags: validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

in the model i have start and end date and i need to compare the start and end dates.i added validation rules for the **format** and custom validation rules for **compare**

```
        [['start_date','end_date'], 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-M-d'],
        ['start_date','validateDates'],


    public function validateDates(){
       if(strtotime($this->end_date) <= strtotime($this->start_date)){
        $this->addError('start_date','Please give correct Start and End dates');
        $this->addError('end_date','Please give correct Start and End dates');
       }
     }
```

i also tried format validation

```
   [['start_date','end_date'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d'],
```

in the view file i customized start and end date for the design

```
                    <?= $form->field($quote, 'start_date',['template' => '{label}{input}<p class="help-block help-block-error">{hint}</p><div class="dtBox"></div>'])->textInput(['data-field' => 'date'])->label("Arrival Date", [
                                'class' => 'control-label quote-layout-text',
                        ]); ?>


                    <?= $form->field($quote, 'end_date',['template' => '{label}{input}<p class="help-block help-block-error">{hint}</p><div class="dtBox"></div>'])->textInput(['data-field' => 'date'])->label("Departure Date", [
                                'class' => 'control-label quote-layout-text',
                        ]); ?>
```

i added start and end date validation to **required** then i get validation messages for the required fields.but i didn't get any validation messages for the **format** and **compare**.

Comment: use any `datepicker` or `maskedInput` first.

Comment: The documentation says: Note: By default, inline validators will not be applied if their associated attributes receive empty inputs or if they have already failed some validation rules. If you want to make sure a rule is always applied, you may configure the skipOnEmpty and/or skipOnError properties to be false in the rule declarations.

Comment: Not only that, @nterms, if anything else fails validation, $model->validate() will not get to the date validation, so date validation can only be tested by ensuring that all other rules pass.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have `{error}` tag in your fields template. Try to add it.

Comment: still not working..but when i make it required the error messages showing as before

Comment: And what if you call `$model->validate()` manually and then print `$model->getErrors()`?

Comment: ..now its working ..i didnt add $model->validate().also its working after the default validation.like if name is required its not showing the date validation after entering the name its showing date validation..